# Unable to SSH into remote server with defined user & keyfile

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys

This one is just bugging me, I can ssh in as USER when I am using USER account

ie:

```
USER@SERVER$ ssh -v USER@ip-SERVER2
```

logs in just fine

if I try and use

```
USER2@SERVER$ ssh -v USER@ip-SERVER2
```

then it fails, and asks for a password

on SERVER2 I've replaced the authorized_keys file and have it down to 2 entries, for USER1 and USER2 from SERVER

this is the debug output from above

```
USER2@SERVER$ ssh -v archer_daemon@ip-SERVER2
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ip-SERVER2 [ip-SERVER2] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /home/USER2/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/USER2/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/USER2/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'ip-SERVER2' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/USER2/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
Address ip-SERVER2 maps to ec2-54-213-211-40.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com, but this does not map back to the address - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_0' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_0' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_0' not found

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/USER2/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /home/USER2/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/USER2/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
archer_daemon@ip-SERVER2's password: 

[root@ip-172-31-44-134 ~]# ssh -v archer_daemon@ip-SERVER2
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ip-SERVER2 [ip-SERVER2] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /home/USER2/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/USER2/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/USER2/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'ip-SERVER2' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/USER2/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
Address ip-SERVER2 maps to ec2-54-213-211-40.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com, but this does not map back to the address - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_0' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_0' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_0' not found

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/USER2/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /home/USER2/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/USER2/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

any ideas?

Comment: You might get more useful info from the server. As root, stop the `sshd` service, run `sshd -d` and try to log on from USER2. After, remember to restart the `sshd` service. The server debug usually will tell you what is wrong.

Comment: it says the publickey is failing, which is expected -- question is why?

Comment: Obvious answer, but does the key in `~user2/id_(d|r)sa.pub` on the client match a line in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server?

Comment: @mtak yes -- I replaced authorized_keys with the user and user2 .pub keys

Answer (score 1):

few hours of banging my head later I got it

```
SERVER2:/home/USER/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

had to add the id_rsa.pub file for USER2 with the tail defined as USER2

ie:

```
ssh-rsa BIGLONGSTRINGOFENCRYPTEDKEYAUTHENTICATION== USER2@ip-SERVER
```

before the key was defined with

```
ssh-rsa BIGLONGSTRINGOFENCRYPTEDKEYAUTHENTICATION== USER@ip-SERVER
```

Comment: Actually the last part (`USER@ip-SERVER`) is only a comment and should not matter. What happens if you change it back to `USER2`?

Comment: @mtak goes back to denying permission -- strange but it works...

Comment: that is really odd. I'd like to investigate further. Could you post your server distro and OpenSSH version?

Comment: CentOS 6.4 (Final)  -- OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010

Comment: I walked in to this while using SFTP to Azure storage accounts as well, it really baffled me...